# Custom Hadoop AMI not working for new instances

Tags: hadoop, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

I would like to create a bare bones hadoop instance for my fellow classmates to get started on hadoop.

Using [this](https://sagarruchandani.wordpress.com/2015/08/01/hadoop-setting-up-hadoop-2-6-0-single-node-on-aws-ec2-ubuntu-ami/) guide, I was able to create an instance with hadoop and everything works just as it should.

However, when I convert it into a public AMI, I can ssh into the new instance, see that hadoop is installed, but when I try to run hadoop, I get an error that says that hadoop cannot connect.

The error I get is :

> ...
>   WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!
>
> ...
>   ECDSA host key for localhost has changed and you have requested strict checking.
>
> ...
>   Host key verification failed.

I am also familiar with whirr and I can get it running fine. With whirr too, if I create an image and run it on a new instance, it runs into the same problem.

My goal is to get my fellow classmates running on hadoop as quickly as possible without setting up java/hadoop or messing with configurations files.

Any suggestions?

Comment: When you create the AMI are you selecting "no reboot"?

Comment: No I am not, can you expand on how that works for AMIs? And where to find that option?

Comment: When you click create image in console the pop up that comes up has that option. http://imgur.com/gallery/7DTlT just try creating an AMI by checking that check box and see if you face that issue?

Comment: I tried that option. However, I still get the same error: WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!
ECDSA host key for localhost has changed and you have requested strict checking.
Host key verification failed.

Comment: I guess this is not issue connecting hadoop before connecting to hadoop run this command "ssh-keygen -R hostname" and then connect to hadoop I guess it will connect.

Comment: So as I understand it, this is a problem with the RSA key. 1)What I don't understand is that when I create a copy of the AMI why the key does not copy over. 2) I tried your method and it did not work 3)I recreated the RSA key using "ssh-keygen -t rsa -P ''"
 and 
"cat $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> $HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys" overwriting the files. This allows me to passwordless ssh "ssh localhost". However, when starting hadoop, it still gets hung up on the key being wrong.

Comment: I guess this not the key but the IP address is getting changes thats why

Comment: Here are some guide for the key pairs http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/building-shared-amis.html